# How to submit form, if input out of shape?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Please tell me how to make it work in older browsers as html5 not understand everything, but inside the form can not be put input:

```
<form onsubmit="checkd();return false" id="form2">
...
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" form="form2" />
```

P.S. I do not know JS, be grateful for a detailed explanation or example ^^

Comment: You need to move the <input> INSIDE the <form></form>

Comment: this is not possible, because they are in different blocks

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you may do something like:

```
$("form2").on("submit", function(){
   ...
});
```